# Why does mobile site scroll left to lots of white space?

Tags: css, mobile

Having a hard time figuring out why my website scrolls way left in the mobile version!

I have checked all of my widths and even tried some suggestion on here but the site still scrolls to the right of the screen! Made sure common viewport code is in the head tag but to no avail. This is a WordPress site based on the twentysixteen theme

There should be no scrolling left or right on the mobile version of my site.

I've been debugging other css issues and this problem is becoming a major headache. Any clue as to what may be causing this width issue with the mobile css?

https://phoenixim.com/liveinhomecare/

CSS Style Sheet
https://phoenixim.com/liveinhomecare/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/style.css?ver=5.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from:

```
.banner {
  margin: 0 -600rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 600rem;
}
```

This code tries to break out of the container using the negative margin/padding trick. To fix this, try:

```
#main {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris. That solved it. I kept thinking it was LR in the ".banner:before" and forget about the ".banner" margin/padding